# Form input values do not update after navigation (Forcing remix to rerender the form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I implemented a simple Master-Detail-View for managing people in my remix web app. On the left, theres a list with all the people and 2 buttons, one for editing and one for deletion. If you click on either the name or one of the buttons, the respective route will be rendered in an outlet next to this list.
The routing is like this:

- `/people/$id` for the simple detail route
- `/people/$id/edit` for the editing route
- `/people/$id/delete` for the deletion route

The editing route contains a form for editing a person. its inputs are prefilled with the current values like this: `defaultValue={person.name}`

If i navigate to this editing route (using a Link tag) after having looked at another route (like simple details or deletion), everything works as expected.
However, if I navigate to this editing route (using a Link tag) after looking at the editing route for a different person, the form will still show all the values for the person i looked at before. The values will update correctly in the DOM, but not on screen. How can i force remix to rerender?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue.
If you're here in the future, look at the [react key prop](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop).